# Kafka server generates a lot of OutOfOrderSequenceException

Tags: apache-kafka

My kafka logs are full of these logs:

```
[2018-09-17 18:36:18,118] ERROR [Replica Manager on Broker 50]: Error processing append operation on partition topic-3 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.OutOfOrderSequenceException: Out of order sequence number for producerId 40141: 3 (incoming seq. number), 136 (current end sequence number)
```

When that happens, the topic becomes under-replicated.
Any ideas?

Kafka version     : 0.11.0.1

Thanks